Integral of $(x^2 + a^2)^n \exp(-x^2)$ from 0 to $\infty$ where n is a positive integer
Is there a closed form solution for the following integral?
$$\int_0^\infty(x^2 + a^2)^n \exp(-x^2)\,dx,$$  where n is a positive integer.
This is an integral that comes up trying to find the inverse Abel transform of a function that approximates a rounded top hat function.

What have you tried? Have you tried any single values, like $n=1?$

If anyone wants to help finding a closed form for
$$\frac{|a|^n\sqrt \pi}{2}\sum_{k\geq 0}\dfrac{(n/2)!(2k)!}{(k!)^2(n/2-k)!}(4a^2)^{-k}\ ?$$
Maybe some hypergeometric function?

My mistake, $n$ is a positive integer. I edited the question

For the case of $n=1$ the answer is the Gaussian integral times $a^2$ plus a solution using the $Erf()$ function that can be found using integration by parts

Assuming $n\in \mathbb{Z}\land n>0\land a\in \mathbb{R}$, Mathematica gives the result $$\int\limits_0^{\infty} \left(a^2+x^2\right)^n, \exp\left(-x^2\right) , dx=\frac{1}{2} \pi (-1)^n , _1\tilde{F}_1\left(-n;\frac{1}{2}-n;a^2\right)$$ in terms of the Hypergeometric1F1Regularized function

@StevenClark. I think that it is $$\frac{ \sqrt{\pi }}{2} ,,
U\left(-n,\frac{1}{2}-n,a^2\right)$$

@ClaudeLeibovici Yes, I believe the two are equivalent for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

@StevenClark. I agréé. I do not know why I do not liké thé regularized version. Cheers :-)

This can be expressed via the Gamma Function.
We begin by expanding the brackets in the Integrand using Binomial Expansion:
$$
\left(a + b\right)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n { n \choose k }a^k b^{n - k} \longrightarrow \left(x^2 + a^2\right)^n =  \sum_{k = 0}^n { n \choose k }\left(x^2\right)^k \left(a^2\right)^{n - k} =   \sum_{k = 0}^n { n \choose k }x^{2k}a^{2(n - k)}
$$
And so our Integral becomes
$$
I = \int_0^\infty \left[ \sum_{k = 0}^n { n \choose k }x^{2k}a^{2(n - k)}\right]e^{-x^2}\:dx =  \sum_{k = 0}^n { n \choose k }a^{2(n - k)}\int_0^\infty x^{2k}e^{-x^2}\:dx =  \sum_{k = 0}^n { n \choose k }a^{2(n - k)}J_k
$$
Where
$$
J_k = \int_0^\infty x^{2k}e^{-x^2}\:dx
$$
To address $J_k$ first let $u = x^2$ and so $du = 2x\:dx = 2\sqrt{u}\:dx$:
$$
J_k = \int_0^\infty u^k e^{-u}\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}\:du = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty u^{k - \frac{1}{2}} e^{-u}\:du = \frac{1}{2}\Gamma\left(k + \frac{1}{2}\right)
$$
Where $\Gamma(x)$ is the Gamma Function. As such, we arrive at our solution for $I$:
$$
I = \sum_{k = 0}^n { n \choose k }a^{2(n - k)}J_k =  \sum_{k = 0}^n { n \choose k }a^{2(n - k)}\Gamma\left(k + \frac{1}{2}\right) =\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k = 0}^n { n \choose k }a^{2(n - k)}\Gamma\left(k + \frac{1}{2}\right)
$$
Whilst this would likely be considered closed form even with the Gamma Function, should you wish to reduce further, you can employ the identity:
$$
\Gamma\left(k + \frac{1}{2}\right)= { k - \frac{1}{2} \choose k}k!\sqrt{\pi}
$$
And so we arrive at:
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{1}{2}  \sum_{k = 0}^n { n \choose k }a^{2(n - k)}\Gamma\left(k + \frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k = 0}^n { n \choose k }a^{2(n - k)}{ k - \frac{1}{2} \choose k}k!\sqrt{\pi}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\sum_{k = 0}^n { n \choose k }a^{2(n - k)}{ k - \frac{1}{2} \choose k}k!
\end{align}
Hope this helps

Hi David, yes that works thank you. I just found another way of doing this without the
Gamma function; you can find the $J_k$ integral using integration by parts, the first term always goes to zero and the second term can be expressed as a value times $J_{k-1}$. This gives the solution shown here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

@Alex - Re Integration by parts - That is one of one the ways the special case of the Gamma Function that I used can be derived.
